# How can I E-mail multiple photos ?

Tags: photos

How do I e-mail multiple Photos from MAC desktop with Yosemite? What is keyboard shortcut to select multiple images and e-mail them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 methods.

One is to hold the "shift" key that will select a continuous group from first to last click.

The other method is to selectively select them.

Click on the first one than HOLD the <kbd>cmd</kbd> key and click on next one and so on while holding the cmd key.

[image: email multiple]

When done selecting release the cmd key, right click on the selection and use the share- email.

Be aware that emailing to large files might fail.

In email check the size and decide if to make it smaller.

[image: email size]

Mail will tell you when to large so either select less or use the "Image size".

[image: size]

Answer (score 0):

A keyboard shortcut might be difficult here (there might be other files on your desktop, or you don't want to send *all* photos currently on the desktop.

I usually do

- select all the photos I want to send (click on first, shift-click on all others)
- right-click on one of them, select "Share" and then "Mail"
- wait for the mail message with the photos to open in Mail (may take some seconds depending on the size and number of photos you've selected)
- enter address, subject etc and send it off